# how to find the largest number in an arraylist of a double

Tags: java, arraylist

> Write a public static method called "ArrayMax" that returns the
> largest number in an ArrayList of Double. (1 mark)
>
> If the input ArrayList is empty then the method should return
> `Double.MIN_VALUE. (1 mark)`
>
> Use the following function prototype when writing the method:

```
public static double ArrayMax(ArrayList<Double> array) {



}
```

This is what I have done so far but its wrong. I tried making an array list, but that wasn't correct either.

```
public static double ArrayMax(ArrayList<Double> array) {

      if (array.isEmpty()) {
    
         return Double.MIN_VALUE;
    
      }


         }
```

How can I the largest number in an arraylist of a double?

Comment: You're not supposed to make an array list, you're supposed to look at the elements in the list, `array`, that is passed to you.  You will need to go through those elements.

Comment: Yeah, and the assignment does not follow the Java Naming Conventions: method names should be written in camelCase (therefore start with lowercase).

Comment: hello hsshshshshsh

Comment: public static String solve(int iterations) { if (iterations <= 1) return null; // Create an initial random starting point String currentSolution = EightQueens.generateRandomStartingPoint(); int currentFitness = EightQueens.calculateFitness(currentSolution); Random random = new Random(); for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) { // Apply a small change operator to the current solution String newSolution = EightQueens.applySmallChangeOperator(currentSolution); int newFitness = EightQueens.calculateFitness(newSolution); // If the new solution has better or equal fitness, update the current solution

Comment: public static Double Q5_fitnessFunction(String solution) { //checking for null if (solution == null) { return null; }//checks for invalid if (solution.length() != 24 || !solution.matches("[01]+")) { return Double.MAX_VALUE; } int[] queens = new int[8]; for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) { queens[i] = Integer.parseInt(solution.substring(i * 3, i * 3 + 3), 2); } int clashes = 0; //finding out number of clashes for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) { for (int j = i + 1; j < 8; j++) { if (Math.abs(queens[i] - queens[j]) == Math.abs(i - j)) { clashes++; } } } //returning the fitness value return 56.0 - clashes; }

Answer (score 0):

What you have so far is good

```
if (array.isEmpty()) {

 return Double.MIN_VALUE;

}
```

Now, create a `Double max` to store the max value that you will return

I would initialize `max` with a value of `Double.MIN_VALUE`

Iterate across `array` and compare each value to `max`

If the value is larger than `max` , set `max = value`

Once you iterate across the entire `array` , simply `return max`

*To iterate across the array, look into using `for each` or simply use indexes starting at `0` and ending before `array.size()`*

**for each**

```
for (Double d : array){
    //Do something with d
}
```

**using indexes**

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
    //Do something with array.get(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about like this.

```
ArrayList<Double> list= new ArrayList<>(List.of(10.3, 4.3, 2.9, 14.6,3.0));
double max = ArrayMax(list);
System.out.println(max);

public static double ArrayMax(ArrayList<Double> array) {
   if(array.isEmpty()) {
       return 1;  // or whatever is required.
   }
   return Collections.max(array);
}
```

prints

```
14.6
```

For more complex objects, you could specify a comparator to get the maximum value based on one or more attributes of that object.  For example:

```
record Person(String name, int age) {} // immutable class - Java 14+

List<Person> people = List.of(new Person("Bob", 18), new Person("Mary", 22), 
             new Person("Jim", 28),new Person("Eve", 21));
Person oldest = Collections.max(people, Comparator.comparing(Person::age));
System.out.println(oldest);
```

prints

```
Person[name=Jim, age=28]
```